# Define and plot the sequence of sum functions

Tags: plotting

How to define the sequence of sum functions and plot this: $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$, where n - natural numbers. I am beginner in Wolfram Mathematica programming. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x[n_] := Refine[Sum[1/(k*(k + 1)), {k, 1, n}], Element[n, Integers]]; 


DiscretePlot[x[n], {n, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x[n], {n, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

x[n_] := Sum[1/(k*(k + 1)), {k, 1, n}]

Show[
 Plot[x[n], {n, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.05}],
 DiscretePlot[x[n], {n, 0, 20}]]
```

[image]

By using [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) the result is defined for smoothly continuous values of `n`

```
xc[n_] = Sum[1/(k*(k + 1)), {k, 1, n}]

(* 1 - 1/(1 + n) *)

Show[
 Plot[xc[n], {n, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.05}],
 DiscretePlot[x[n], {n, 0, 20}]]
```

[image]